# Issue with style tag and alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am having an issue in the div class that I created named section1, where the paragraph wont align left and when I try to edit the style of it in the style tag under the closed head, .section1 does not show up and does not work when I set the alignment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">



</head>
<style>
    body {margin:0;}
    .Header {
        z-index: 100;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        height: 70px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        .Header.responsive {position: relative;}
        .Header.responsive li.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

    }
    @media (max-width: 960px){
    .Header .headerLogo{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 86px;
        height: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    }
    .headerLogo{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: small;
        font-style: italic;
        font-family: Verdana;
        color: white;

    }


</style>
<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">


    </a>
</div>
</body>

<body>


<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src= style="width:100%">
    <!--<img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_rr_02.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_rr_03.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_rr_04.jpg" style="width:100%"> _-->
    <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="section1" align="left" style = "background-color: black; color: white; padding: 500px">
    <a class = "header1">
    <h1 align="left" style = "font-size: x-large">A new way to fold a board</h1>
        <p></p>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
        x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(carousel, 5000);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the value of `padding` in below code.

```
<div id="section1" align="left" style = "background-color: black; color: white; padding: 500px">
```

Below is updated snippet.

```html
I am having an issue in the div class that I created named section1, where the paragraph wont align left and when I try to edit the style of it in the style tag under the closed head, .section1 does not show up and does not work when I set the alignment.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Lunation Boards</title>

</head>
<style>
    body {margin:0;}
    .Header {
        z-index: 100;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        height: 70px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        .Header.responsive {position: relative;}
        .Header.responsive li.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

    }
    @media (max-width: 960px){
    .Header .headerLogo{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 86px;
        height: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    }
    .headerLogo{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: small;
        font-style: italic;
        font-family: Verdana;
        color: white;

    }


</style>
<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <h1>Lunation Boards</h1>

    </a>
</div>
</body>

<body>


<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="file:///C:/Users/noaht/Downloads/skateboard.pdf" style="width:100%">
    <!--<img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_rr_02.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_rr_03.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_rr_04.jpg" style="width:100%"> _-->
    <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="section1" align="left" style = "background-color: black; color: white; padding: 10px; min-height:80vh">
    <a class = "header1">
    <h1 align="left" style = "font-size: x-large">A new way to fold a board</h1>
        <p></p>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
        x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(carousel, 5000);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So that works with alignment but I am trying to make that section bigger which it is when the padding is at 500px

Comment: check the updated snippet. I have added `min-height:80vh` to the `div`, hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

The  align attribute is not supported in HTML5. As you have declared document type html which is of HTML5. Use CSS instead.

You can add style attribute style="text-align:left";

Answer (score 0):

So the fix would be to make your `display: inline-block` and `width:100%`. Doing this will give you the effect you are looking for.
Now your h1 will be hidden cause of your header. So just give it a margin-top and you'll be good to go.

```
<div id="section1" align="left" style = "background-color: black; color: white; padding-top:500px; display:inline-block;width:100%;">
  <a class = "header1">
    <h1 align="left" style = "margin-top:50px; font-size: x-large">A new way to fold a board</h1>
    <p></p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove align attribute in the h1 tag in the setction1 div.
2. Change the padding to 500px 0 500px 0 instead of 500px. You can  increases the left/right margins as you want.
3. Not sure if I understand you question. You mean the style of .section1 doesn't work? If you put the style in css, you need to declare it as #section1 instead of .section1 or you have to add a class="section1" in the div tag attribute

Try this:

```css
    body {margin:0;}
    .Header {
        z-index: 100;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        height: 70px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        .Header.responsive {position: relative;}
        .Header.responsive li.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

    }
    @media (max-width: 960px){
    .Header .headerLogo{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 86px;
        height: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    }
    .headerLogo{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: small;
        font-style: italic;
        font-family: Verdana;
        color: white;

    }

#section1 {
   text-align:left; 
   background-color: black;
   color: white; 
   padding: 500px 0 500px 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <h1>Lunation Boards</h1>

    </a>
</div>
</body>

<body>


<div class="w3-content w3-section" style="max-width:500px">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="file:///C:/Users/noaht/Downloads/skateboard.pdf" style="width:100%">
    <!--<img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_rr_02.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_rr_03.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_rr_04.jpg" style="width:100%"> _-->
    <div class="w3-center w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
        <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="section1">
    <a class = "header1">
    <h1  style = "font-size: x-large">A new way to fold a board</h1>
        <p></p>
    </a>
</div>

<script>
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}
        x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(carousel, 5000);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

[Edit] 
1. Move section1 style to css
2. The most import thing for align to work is to use text-align instead of align as Devendra mentioned.

Comment: I originally had the class = section1, then I changed it to id but .section1 or #section doesnt show up in styles as I type it. Even if i go ahead and type the styles to #section, it doesnt work.

Comment: Please see my edit. I've moved the section1 style to css. You should use #section1 not #section. If you set 'padding:500px;', the text will be centered because of the padding and you won't see the align effect change. Imagine an object surrounded by sponge and put in a box. That's why I set it to 500px 0, just to see the effect. You can change the design for your requirement.

Comment: If you use class, you should write class="section1" and a .section1 in css. Notice the quote marks.